# Can't find methods in pocketsphinx module (Python3.4 on windows)

Tags: python, python-3.x, pocketsphinx

I'm trying to use the PocketSphinx python module, I downloaded PyPocketSphinx via [pypi.python.org](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/PyPocketSphinx/12608) using the win32-py3.4 link. But when I can't make this simple code working using the interpreter:

```
import pocketsphinx as ps
dec = ps.Decoder()
```

"AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'Decoder'

When checking the module via: `dir(ps)`, I have:

```
['__builtins__', '__cached__', '__doc__', '__file__', '__loader__', '__name__', '__package__', '__path__', '__spec__']
```

And `print(ps.__file__)` gave me the right path (C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\pocketsphinx__init__.py)

I'm a bit lost why python find the correct module but can't figure out the methods within.

Would you have an idea ?
Thanks in advance,

Comment: You have an `AttributeError` not `importError` . so you may be sure that `pocketsphinx` module have `Decoder` or maybe you have a typo !

Comment: In the module directory, the pocketsphinx.py define a class `Decoder`. I took the sample code from a pocketsphinx example, so no typo :s

Comment: Do you have CMU SphinxBase and PocketSphinx installed ?

Comment: I do: I edit the PATH env variable to point to the sphinxbase.dll and pocketsphinx.dll. But if it was a missing dependencies, shouldn't I have a exception when I try to import the module ?